# Display another HTML in div from main HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a simple HTML (`Home.html`) that has an `iframe`. This `iframe` is used for displaying page `Grid.aspx`. Everything works fine, but my organization does not allow the use of an `iframe` for this project. The IT department that admins the server where the IIS is installed **does not want me to use them**.

Can I use a `div` or another element instead?

This is my html with the IFrame that I need to replace and the current JavaScript I use to load content in that IFrame:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="storeTable" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;"> 
    <iframe id="retailframe" src="" width="900px" height="800px" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" ></iframe> 
</div>
    <input type="button" value="Capacity Chart" onclick="CapacityChart();">
    <script>
function CapacityChart()
{
    var doc = document.getElementById('retailframe').contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write('Test');
    doc.close();
    var storeSite = "http://10.12.34.83:88/Grid.aspx";
    var store = document.getElementById('retailframe');
    store.src = storeSite;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I load the content of the Grid.aspx in a div instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading the page into an `iframe`, you can make an **[AJAX call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)** to the server and take the response (the page's contents) and load it into any element you like. But, **[there are security concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)** with AJAX calls and, depending on the site you want to connect to, you may not be able to do this.

```html
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="storeTable" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Capacity Chart" onclick="CapacityChart();">
  <script>
      // Create instance of XHR to make AJAX call with:
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
      // Configure the component to make the call:
      xhr.open("GET", "http://10.12.34.83:88/Grid.aspx");
      
      // Set up an event handler that will fire as the call moves through its various stages
      xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(){
         
         // If the response has been recieved
         if(xhr.readyState === 4){
            // And the status is "OK"
            if(xhr.status === 200){
              // Inject the results into the container of choice:
              document.getElementById("storeTable").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;   
            } else {
              console.log("Problem getting data");
            }
         } 
      
      });
      
      xhr.send(); // Make the call
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably won't work. It's a cross-origin request. This would also break any JavaScript in the frame.

Comment: @Quentin My answer has been updated to address CORS and there no longer is any frame. And, given the restrictions indicated in the question, this is the solution.